# How do I remove transit lines from the transit layer? (Documented method doesn't seem to work.)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the transit layer enabled on a map of San Francisco, though I've checked other cities and this problem seems to exist everywhere. I want to see the transit stops but remove the transit lines. I'm using the documented code for turning off the visibility of features, which seems to work on everything except transit lines. For example, if I use this:

```
var foo = [
  {
    featureType: "transit",
    elementType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]

map.setOptions({styles: foo});
```

It removes the bus and light rail stop icons, but not the bus and light rail lines, even though the documentation says it should affect both stops and lines. (You may have to zoom in further to see all the thin blue bus lines.) If I specifically select "transit.line", nothing is removed at all. I can remove "poi" or other features with this method, just not transit lines. I also can't change the weight, color, or other styles of transit lines. I'm wondering if this is because transit lines come in different colors and weights depending on whether they're bus or metro lines and depending on if they have an assigned line color. Perhaps all styles are disabled, then, including visibility? Or perhaps there's an undocumented feature type that selects bus and metro lines?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ME2LJ/

Comment: Sounds like you are adding the [TransitLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TransitLayer) then trying to [style the map tiles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), hard to tell from the code you posted.  Do you have a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm doing. Now I'm trying to make Google Maps load in a way jsfiddle likes...

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ME2LJ/

Answer (score 0):

The [Styled Maps styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) doesn't apply to the [TransitLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TransitLayer)

Comment: Well, if there's some official statement somewhere, I guess that's that. But styling does work on the transit layer if you're styling transit.stations or poi, roads, etc. But if there's an acknowledgement somewhere that it just doesn't apply to transit.lines, I guess a feature request is the best I can do.

Comment: Is there an official statement somewhere that says it does?  Or is that what you have found?

Comment: I'm confused. You said styling doesn't apply to the transit layer. I don't know this to be the case, so that's why I hedged everything with "_if_ there's some official statement" and "_if_ there's an acknowledgement somewhere."